# Unable to live boot Kubuntu 18.04.1 USB on MSI GL62 6QF laptop

Tags: boot, kubuntu

I am trying to re-partition & reinstall my existing Kubuntu installation on my MSI GL62 6QF laptop (upgraded with 32GB ram since last install).

I can see the Kubuntu choice screen without giving any options.
[image: Kubuntu choice screen]

But if I click on "Try Kubuntu", the system just freezes up.

I overcame this issue by using the `nomodeset` boot parameter. However, the setup just stops at the next screen.
[image: Splash screen after Try Kubuntu with nomodeset]

Here's the same step without `quiet splash`.
[image: Screen after Try Kubuntu with nomodeset and without quiet splash]

So far, I've tried.

- Toggling CPU C States option
- `nouveau.modeset=0`
- `pci=nomsi`
- `acpi_osi=Linux`

Also, I'm on **Legacy** boot mode, as the USB is never booting in any other modes.

Maybe unrelated, but the USB only boots properly in one USB port (USB2vs3 issue).

Edit:
Additionally, here's all my BIOS options:
[image: BIOS Advanced tab screen]
[image: BIOS Boot options tab screen]

Comment: In the grub menu try `quiet splash acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only `acpi=off`.

Turns out `nomodeset` is totally unnecessary (harmful) and even `nomodeset acpi=off` halts the booting for this laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Go to BIOS and disable your graphics memory, and try again.

Comment: There's no option for that. You can check for yourself in my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable **secure boot**

Comment: There's no option for secure boot. I've edited my question to show all BIOS boot settings.